# XtraTabbedMdiManager xclude one form from getting tabbed

Tags: .net, devexpress

I have this XtraTabbedMdiManager component on the main form that automatically makes every form that is a child as a tab.

Now I want one form to be a child of the main but it should not be as a tab.

How can this be done.

Comment: I see they've added this option in the newer version of the component. (http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTabbedMdiXtraTabbedMdiManager_Floattopic) but I still use the 2009 version, is there any way to make that work with the old version?

Comment: Use a UserControl instead of a Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an old version, I am afraid it is impossible to achieve this effect :(.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
if (this.ActiveMdiChild != null)
  this.ActiveMdiChild.Close();
  CustData customers = new CustData();
  customers.MdiParent = this;
  customers.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
  customers.Show();
```

Comment: There is something wrong with indentation. Please, improve your formatting.